# when I run the application it shows the message your application has stopped unexpectedly what is wrong?

Tags: android

Here is my log cat

**Log cat**

```
11-04 10:19:39.718: D/dalvikvm(341): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 74K, 51% free 2637K/5379K, external 2730K/3266K, paused 47ms
11-04 10:19:40.048: D/dalvikvm(341): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 51% free 2637K/5379K, external 6054K/7560K, paused 40ms
11-04 10:19:40.258: D/AndroidRuntime(341): Shutting down VM
11-04 10:19:40.258: W/dalvikvm(341): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bank.logged/com.bank.logged.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.bank.logged.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-04 10:19:40.268: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  ... 11 more
11-04 10:19:49.548: I/Process(341): Sending signal. PID: 341 SIG: 9
11-04 10:22:18.638: D/dalvikvm(374): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 75K, 51% free 2637K/5379K, external 2730K/3266K, paused 89ms
11-04 10:22:18.988: D/dalvikvm(374): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 51% free 2637K/5379K, external 6054K/7560K, paused 40ms
11-04 10:22:19.208: D/AndroidRuntime(374): Shutting down VM
11-04 10:22:19.208: W/dalvikvm(374): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bank.logged/com.bank.logged.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at com.bank.logged.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-04 10:22:19.218: E/AndroidRuntime(374):  ... 11 more
11-04 10:22:22.448: I/Process(374): Sending signal. PID: 374 SIG: 9
11-04 10:22:26.128: D/dalvikvm(384): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 76K, 51% free 2637K/5379K, external 2730K/3266K, paused 59ms
11-04 10:22:26.478: D/dalvikvm(384): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 51% free 2637K/5379K, external 6054K/7560K, paused 40ms
11-04 10:22:26.698: D/AndroidRuntime(384): Shutting down VM
11-04 10:22:26.698: W/dalvikvm(384): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bank.logged/com.bank.logged.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at com.bank.logged.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384):  ... 11 more
11-04 10:22:35.798: I/Process(384): Sending signal. PID: 384 SIG: 9
11-04 10:24:43.168: D/dalvikvm(393): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 66K, 51% free 2637K/5379K, external 2730K/3266K, paused 46ms
11-04 10:24:43.518: D/dalvikvm(393): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 51% free 2637K/5379K, external 6054K/7560K, paused 39ms
11-04 10:24:43.738: D/AndroidRuntime(393): Shutting down VM
11-04 10:24:43.738: W/dalvikvm(393): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bank.logged/com.bank.logged.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at com.bank.logged.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-04 10:24:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  ... 11 more
```

**This is my code**

```
package com.bank.logged;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.view.Menu;
//import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call);
        call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent makecall = new Intent
                        (Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel 0774459581") );
                            startActivity(makecall);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: post your activity_main.xml

Comment: @MD provided the answer...

Answer (score 2):

Your logcat clearly said:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton 11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384): at
```

You're trying to cast `ImageButton` to `Button` and it's wrong.So do as below,

```
ImageButton call = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.call);
```

and make sure you've `ImageButton` with id **call** in your `activity_main.xml` layout...

Answer (score 1):

Need to use :

```
  Intent makecall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);          
  makecall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0774459581"));          
  startActivity(makecall);
```

Also you have

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton 11-04 10:22:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(384): at
```

So must be sure there is `ImageButton` in your xml file.

If in your xml file there is ImageButton then need to change

```
 Button call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call);
```

to

```
 ImageButton call = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.call);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Button  to ImageButton

```
ImageButton ImageButtoncall = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.call);
ImageButtoncall.callsetOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent makecall = new Intent
                    (Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel 0774459581") );
                        startActivity(makecall);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the code in this way

```
 Intent makecall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

 makecall.setData(Uri.parse("tel 0774459581")J);

 startActivity(makecall);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your XML probably you are having **ImageButton** which you are trying to assign to **Button** which is wrong.

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.widget.ImageView
           ↳    android.widget.ImageButton
```

> Use ImageButton or any of its ancestor